# How do I put this results on the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Results of each soccer game are given in an array, and now i want to do a standings table out of it, so i started to sort out the results and add them to the particular team, in this case i want to add up all Goals scored by that team (GF) and Points of that team (PTS)

But, with my code i get this results

```
Group A        PTS       GF
0                        6
Barcelona                2
```

What in fact i want to achieve is this :

```
Group A        PTS       GF

Barcelona      6         2
```

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Here is my code down below, that I've tried so far

```
results:[
{
Group:"A"
Home: "Fc Barcelona",
Away: "Fc Porto"
Score: {
Home: 1,
Away: 0,
Pts: {
Home:0,
Away:0
}
},
{
Group:"A"
Home: "Fc Barcelona",
Away: "AC Milan"
Score: {
Home: 1,
Away: 0,
Pts: {
Home:0,
Away:0
}
},


   <table  class="table">
        <div v-for="(g, grpname) in groups" :key="grpname.index">
        <thead class="thead">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">{{grpname}}</th>
                <th scope="col">PTS</th>
                <th scope="col">GF</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

            <tbody>

                    <tr v-for="(pts, tname) in g" :key="pts.index">

                        <td>{{tname}}</td>
                        <td>{{pts}}</td>
                    </tr>


            </tbody>

data () {
    return {
        groups: {},
        axiosResults:{}
    }

mounted () {

        this.transformResults();
},

methods: {

     transformResults() {
      const result = {};
      axiosResults.forEach((obj) => {
        if (!(obj.Group in result)) {
          result[obj.Group] = {};
        }


        const g = result[obj.Group];
        if (!(obj.Home in g)) {
          g[obj.Home] = 0;
        }
        if (!(obj.Away in g)) {
          g[obj.Away] = 0;
        }
        if (!(obj.Pts.Home in g)) {
          g[obj.Pts.Home] = 0;
        }



        g[obj.Home] += obj.Score.Home;
        g[obj.Away] += obj.Score.Away;

        if (obj.Score.Home>obj.Score.Away) {
            g[obj.Pts.Home] += 3

        }



      });
      this.groups = result;


    }
```

Comment: What library for design are you using, vuetify? bootstrap?

Comment: @Deda boostrap 4x

Comment: Vue-bootstrap ?

Comment: @Deda no just bootstrap, linking directly to index.html

Answer (score 0):

For the array from above this template should work, if the array from above is not a final array, please provide example structure.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Group</th>
      <th scope="col">Home</th>
      <th scope="col">Away</th>
      <th scope="col">PTS</th>
      <th scope="col">GF</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(result,index) in results" :key="index">
      <th scope="row">{{result.Group}}</th>
      <td>{{result.Home}}</td>
      <td>{{result.Away}}</td>
      <td>{{result.Score.Home + result.Score.Away}}</td>
      <td>{{result.Pts.Home + result.Pts.Away}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this doesnt work in my case, Sorry i forgot to put my template part of the code, please check my template part and see if you can tell me how i do it right

Comment: show me an example of `groups` variable, console log it.

Comment: groups contains this :
{
Group A:
0:0,
FC Barcelona:0
}

g contains :
{
0:6,
FC Barcelona:2
}
}